# How Can I dynamically add route path in URL Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an multiple options to go on detail page of listing eg:
 1) option
 2) option 1
 3) option 2
 4) option 3
All the option go on to the same detail page with different content and what I want in the URL is what user Chooses eg:
mydoamin/option/detail-page or mydoamin/option 1/detail-page

Whatever user chooses I want it on my URL as per the requirement and I am getting these options dynamically from server.

Please suggest Something for that.

Comment: why don't you use [placeholder token](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter) in the url like /mydomain/:myoption/detail-page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this perhaps:

```
changePath(path: string) {
  this.router.navigate(['mydoamin/' + path + '/detail-page'])
};
```

Also, in `constructor()`  import [Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) like this: `constructor(private router: Router)`.

Then, call this function from `html` page (*detail page*) and pass the path (the dynamic route). Like this:

```
<button (click)="changePath(dynamicPathName)">Change Page</button>
```

*Optionally,* you can pass `queryParams` to the router like this: `this.route.navigate(['path'], {queryParams: {params: id}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [Angular Route Defination with paramater](https://angular.io/guide/router#route-definition-with-a-parameter).

Here you can define a placeholder for the dynamic parameter in routing strategy

```
{ path: 'custom/:param', component: CustomComponent }
```

The same could be accessed using the [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
        console.log(params.get('param')))
    );
  }
}
```

You can follow the [example from angular guide](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qrngbdxkekm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fhero-detail.component.ts) for more information